# Creating gap in \hline of tabular

Tags: tables

Often I read questions asking how to remove the gap between two `\hlines` in a table, but I like the gap and want to create it in the `\hline` as well, to have an equal effect for the column and row titles.

The code below makes a standard table

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c||c|c|c|}\hline
& A & B & C\\\hline\hline
A & 1 & 2 & 3\\\hline
B & 4 & 5 & 6\\\hline
C & 7 & 8 & 9\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The image shows what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Does a simple way to create this table exsist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If such a setup is really needed use `\cline{...}` for the rules and add a very small 'empty' column as the 2nd one.

The empty row can be done with `\multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\[-0.8\normalbaselineskip]`, for example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|@{}p{2pt}@{}|c|c|c|}
  \cline{3-5}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & &  A & B & C\\
   \cline{3-5}
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{} \\[-0.8\normalbaselineskip]
  \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
  A && 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
B && 4 & 5 & 6\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
C && 7 & 8 & 9\\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Christian! What is the reasoning to say "if it is really needed"? Is this typographically incorrect, or is it in your opinion not astatically pleasing?

Comment: @Douwe66: `typographically` incorrect is a stretchable term. There might be occasions where such a table is nice (i.e. in a fill - in form, for example), or in education to show some specific content. I would not use it for larger tables, however